# Как привязать два onsubmit к одной форме?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть два события, их необходимо после sumbit выполнить, однако вот незадача: не могу их привязать дабы все работало одновременно:

```
 <form action="" name="add_persons" method="post" onsubmit="addRow();return false;" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не понятно зачем тут сама форма, если в итоге она никуда не отправляется Подумайте над этим.

А в целом, тут проще использовать не инлайн обработчики, а как делают большинство: применяют **[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**.

В итоге надо повесить слушатель на форму для события `submit`. Далее не забыть в самом начале метода сделать **[preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)**, ну а в самом методе вначале сделать валидацию. Если не прошла - показываем ошибки, если прошла - делаем `addRow`